# Wordpress child theme - modifying file of includes folder

Tags: php, wordpress, function, themes

I know there are many others who are trying to deal with that problem, but I didn't find an answer.

I'd like to modify a **file** which is located **in** the **includes folder** of a theme.

I need to change the following line:

```
$html .= '<span class="profile-widget-info-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> <a href="'.get_author_posts_url(get_current_user_id()).'">'.__('Channel','mars').'</a></span>';
```

of this  file: http://pastebin.com/Qm5r9NeW

How can I do this in my **child theme**?

Thank you all in advance,
Jake

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file you have pasted to your child theme.

At the very top you will see an if statement that is checking if a function already exists. By placing this file in your child theme, the file will run first and prevent the parent theme from adding the function. You will need to change the name of the widget class so you don't cause a conflict. I've changed the class name from **Mars_LoginForm_Widget_Class** to **Jake_LoginForm_Widget_Class**.

```
if( !defined('ABSPATH') ) exit;
if( !function_exists('Mars_LoginForm_Widget') ){
    function Mars_LoginForm_Widget() {
        register_widget('Jake_LoginForm_Widget_Class');
    }
    add_action('widgets_init', 'Mars_LoginForm_Widget');
}
```

Now you also need to update the class name in the class definition to match the name you've given the class above.

```
class Jake_LoginForm_Widget_Class extends WP_Widget{
```

After that just make sure you are including this file in your child theme and then you can freely edit the widget class.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer!! But it doesn't work :/ My changes still don't appear..

Comment: You may need to re-add the widget.

Comment: Thank you, but this did not fix the problem too :/

Comment: Where are you including the file from?

Comment: I pasted the file in my child theme which is linked to the theme "videotube"

Comment: You need to include the file via php's `include` function. In your child theme's functions.php add `include "your-pasted-filename.php";`